# Slide and push menu not functioning correctly.

Tags: javascript, html, css, menu

While building a new site I attempted to use a slide/push menu from Codrops located [here.](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/04/17/slide-and-push-menus/)

I have, to my knowledge, placed all of the correct code into my file but cant get the menu to open.

If I change my button class to showRight I can get the menu to open but when changing it to showRightPush to get the menu to push the body to the left it doesn't work.

Can someone please take a look at my jsfiddle located [here,](https://jsfiddle.net/patricksharer/e1dxygqb/#&togetherjs=IjsVaHRPyk) to help me figure out what I've done wrong?

My code is also below.

Thanks!

```js
// ===== Side Menu Hide Show
//===================================================================================================== 

$(function() {
    var menuVisible = false;
    $('#showRight').click(function() {
        if (menuVisible) {
            $('.cbp-spmenu').css({
                'display': 'none'
            });
            menuVisible = false;
            return;
        }
        $('.cbp-spmenu').css({
            'display': 'block'
        });
        menuVisible = true;
    });
    var menuVisible = false;
    $('#close').click(function() {
        if (menuVisible) {
            $('.cbp-spmenu').css({
                'display': 'none'
            });
            menuVisible = false;
            return;
        }
        $('.cbp-spmenu').css({
            'display': 'block'
        });
        menuVisible = true;
    });
});




/*!
 * classie - class helper functions
 * from bonzo https://github.com/ded/bonzo
 * 
 * classie.has( elem, 'my-class' ) -> true/false
 * classie.add( elem, 'my-new-class' )
 * classie.remove( elem, 'my-unwanted-class' )
 * classie.toggle( elem, 'my-class' )
 */

/*jshint browser: true, strict: true, undef: true */

( function( window ) {

'use strict';

// class helper functions from bonzo https://github.com/ded/bonzo

function classReg( className ) {
  return new RegExp("(^|\\s+)" + className + "(\\s+|$)");
}

// classList support for class management
// altho to be fair, the api sucks because it won't accept multiple classes at once
var hasClass, addClass, removeClass;

if ( 'classList' in document.documentElement ) {
  hasClass = function( elem, c ) {
    return elem.classList.contains( c );
  };
  addClass = function( elem, c ) {
    elem.classList.add( c );
  };
  removeClass = function( elem, c ) {
    elem.classList.remove( c );
  };
}
else {
  hasClass = function( elem, c ) {
    return classReg( c ).test( elem.className );
  };
  addClass = function( elem, c ) {
    if ( !hasClass( elem, c ) ) {
      elem.className = elem.className + ' ' + c;
    }
  };
  removeClass = function( elem, c ) {
    elem.className = elem.className.replace( classReg( c ), ' ' );
  };
}

function toggleClass( elem, c ) {
  var fn = hasClass( elem, c ) ? removeClass : addClass;
  fn( elem, c );
}

window.classie = {
  // full names
  hasClass: hasClass,
  addClass: addClass,
  removeClass: removeClass,
  toggleClass: toggleClass,
  // short names
  has: hasClass,
  add: addClass,
  remove: removeClass,
  toggle: toggleClass
};

})( window );




var menuLeft = document.getElementById( 'cbp-spmenu-s1' ),
    menuRight = document.getElementById( 'cbp-spmenu-s2' ),
    menuTop = document.getElementById( 'cbp-spmenu-s3' ),
    menuBottom = document.getElementById( 'cbp-spmenu-s4' ),
    showLeft = document.getElementById( 'showLeft' ),
    showRight = document.getElementById( 'showRight' ),
    showTop = document.getElementById( 'showTop' ),
    showBottom = document.getElementById( 'showBottom' ),
    showLeftPush = document.getElementById( 'showLeftPush' ),
    showRightPush = document.getElementById( 'showRightPush' ),
    body = document.body;

   showLeft.onclick = function() {
    classie.toggle( this, 'active' );
    classie.toggle( menuLeft, 'cbp-spmenu-open' );
    disableOther( 'showLeft' );
   };
   showRight.onclick = function() {
    classie.toggle( this, 'active' );
    classie.toggle( menuRight, 'cbp-spmenu-open' );
    disableOther( 'showRight' );
   };
   showTop.onclick = function() {
    classie.toggle( this, 'active' );
    classie.toggle( menuTop, 'cbp-spmenu-open' );
    disableOther( 'showTop' );
   };
   showBottom.onclick = function() {
    classie.toggle( this, 'active' );
    classie.toggle( menuBottom, 'cbp-spmenu-open' );
    disableOther( 'showBottom' );
   };
   showLeftPush.onclick = function() {
    classie.toggle( this, 'active' );
    classie.toggle( body, 'cbp-spmenu-push-toright' );
    classie.toggle( menuLeft, 'cbp-spmenu-open' );
    disableOther( 'showLeftPush' );
   };
   showRightPush.onclick = function() {
    classie.toggle( this, 'active' );
    classie.toggle( body, 'cbp-spmenu-push-toleft' );
    classie.toggle( menuRight, 'cbp-spmenu-open' );
    disableOther( 'showRightPush' );
   };

   function disableOther( button ) {
    if( button !== 'showLeft' ) {
     classie.toggle( showLeft, 'disabled' );
    }
    if( button !== 'showRight' ) {
     classie.toggle( showRight, 'disabled' );
    }
    if( button !== 'showTop' ) {
     classie.toggle( showTop, 'disabled' );
    }
    if( button !== 'showBottom' ) {
     classie.toggle( showBottom, 'disabled' );
    }
    if( button !== 'showLeftPush' ) {
     classie.toggle( showLeftPush, 'disabled' );
    }
    if( button !== 'showRightPush' ) {
     classie.toggle( showRightPush, 'disabled' );
    }
   }

// ===== Side Menu Drop Downs
//===================================================================================================== 
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.parent').click(function() {
        $(".parent").not(this).find(".sub-nav").removeClass('visible').slideUp();
        $(this).find('.sub-nav').toggleClass('visible').slideToggle();
    });
});
```

```css
/***** PAGE SETUP *****
***************************************************************/
a,abbr,acronym,address,applet,article,aside,audio,b,big,blockquote,body,canvas,caption,center,cite,code,dd,del,details,dfn,dialog,div,dl,dt,em,embed,fieldset,figcaption,figure,font,footer,form,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,header,hgroup,hr,html,i,iframe,img,ins,kbd,label,legend,li,main,mark,menu,meter,nav,object,ol,output,p,pre,progress,q,rp,rt,ruby,s,samp,section,small,span,strike,strong,sub,summary,sup,table,tbody,td,tfoot,th,thead,time,tr,tt,u,ul,var,video,xmp {
    border: 0;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
}

html,
body {
    height: 100%;
}

article,
aside,
details,
figcaption,
figure,
footer,
header,
hgroup,
main,
menu,
nav,
section {
    display: block;
}

b,
strong {
    font-weight: bold;
}

img {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    color: transparent;
    font-size: 0;
    vertical-align: middle;
    -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;
}

ul,
ol {
    list-style: none;
}

li {
    display: list-item;
}

table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}

th,
td,
caption {
    font-weight: normal;
    vertical-align: top;
    text-align: left;
}

q {
    quotes: none;
}

q:before,
q:after {
    content: "";
    content: none;
}

body {
    font: 18px / 1.5 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
    color: #384554;
    font-weight: 300;
}

hr {
    border-top: 1px solid #eee ;
    clear: both;
    height: 0;
    width: 80%;
    margin: 30px 0 0 0;
    padding: 0 10px;
}

i {
    color: rgba(22, 156, 208, 0.83);
}

h1 { font-size: 25px; }
h2 { font-size: 23px; }
h3 { font-size: 21px; }
h4 { font-size: 19px; }
h5 { font-size: 17px; }
h6 { font-size: 15px; }

ol {
    list-style: decimal;
}

ul {
    list-style: disc;
}

li {
    margin-left: 30px;
}

h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6{
   font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif; 
}

p,
dl,
hr,
ol,
ul,
pre,
table,
address,
fieldset,
figure {
    font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
}

body {
    background: #fff;
    color: #4c5867;
    text-align: center;
}

a {
    font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;
    color: #4c5867;
    text-decoration: none;
}
a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #169CD0;
}
.button {
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: #169CD0;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    color: #fff;
    border-radius: 5px;
    font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: 300;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
.button-orange {
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: #FF9C00;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    color: #fff;
    border-radius: 5px;
    font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: 300;
    text-transform: uppercase;
        margin: 25px 0 0 0;
}
.btn-left {
    float: left;
}
.button:hover {
    background-color: rgba(22, 156, 208, 0.83);
    color: #fff;
}
.button i, .button-orange i {
    color: #fff;
}
.hideme {
    opacity: 0;
}
.hideme-side {
  opacity: 0;
  position: relative;
}
/*animation element sliding left*/

.hideme-side.slide-left {
  opacity: 0;
  -moz-transition: all 500ms linear;
  -webkit-transition: all 500ms linear;
  -o-transition: all 500ms linear;
  transition: all 500ms linear;
  -moz-transform: translate3d(-100px, 0px, 0px);
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(-100px, 0px, 0px);
  -o-transform: translate(-100px, 0px);
  -ms-transform: translate(-100px, 0px);
  transform: translate3d(-100px, 0px, 0px);
}

.hideme-side.slide-left.in-view {
  opacity: 1;
  -moz-transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);
  -o-transform: translate(0px, 0px);
  -ms-transform: translate(0px, 0px);
  transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);
}

/***** PUSH PULL CLASSES *****
***************************************************************/

.grid-container > hr {
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

div[class*="push-"] section {
  /**background: #dec;**/
}

div[class*="pull-"] section {
  /**background: #fcd;**/
}

.dynamic-px-width {
  /**display: block;**/
}

/***** Above Header *****
****************************************************************************/

.pre-above-head {
    background-color: #f2f2f2; 
    height: 30px;
}
#above-head {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 30px;
}
.above-head-left {
    text-align: left; 
    float: left;
    font-size: 14px;
    padding-right: 25px;
    font-weight: 300;
    padding: 4px 0 0 0;
}
.above-head-contacts {
    float: right;
    padding: 0 0 0 20px;
}
.social-bar a {
    display: inline-block;
    float: right;
    width: 1.3em;
    height: 1.3em;
    margin: 3px 5px 0 5px;
    color: #4c5867;
    background-color: #fff;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
        -moz-border-radius: 50%;
            border-radius: 50%;
}
.social-bar i {
    color: #4c5867;
}
.social-bar i:hover {
    color: #169CD0;
    transition: all .25s ease;
}

/***** HEADER *****
****************************************************************************/
.pre-head {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
#head_container {
    display: block;
    padding: 0;
}
.compact {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.head {
    padding: 20px 0 5px 0;
}
#header {
    height: auto;
    position: relative;
}
.menu-hamburger {
    margin: 0 0 px 0;
}
.fatnav_header #header_logo {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1001;
    margin: -5px 0 0 0;
}
#fat_nav {
    padding: 0;
    text-align: right;
}
.fatnav_header ul,
.fatnav_header li {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
#nav li {
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: left;
    font-weight: 400;
    color: #fff;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.parent a{
    border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
}
.sub-nav {
    background: rgba(18, 107, 142, 0.22);
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px -4px 7px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.11);
        -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px -4px 7px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.11);
            box-shadow: inset 0px -4px 7px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.11);
}
.sub-nav li a {
    padding: 10px 0 10px 30px;
    border: none;
}
.nav-top i {
    color: #fff;
}
#showRightPush {
    background: none;
    border: none;
}
#showRightPush img {
    width: 95px;
    padding: 0;
    float: right;
}
#close {
    background: none;
    border: none;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 21px 0 0 0;
    width: 100%;
}
#close img {
    width: 25px;
    float: right;
    padding: 0 20px 0 0;
}
.cbp-spmenu {
 background: #169CD0;
 position: fixed;
    overflow: auto;
}

.cbp-spmenu h3 {
 color: #afdefa;
 font-size: 1.9em;
 padding: 20px;
 margin: 0;
 font-weight: 300;
 background: #169CD0;
}

.cbp-spmenu a {
 display: block;
 color: #fff;
 font-size: 1.1em;
 font-weight: 300;
}

.cbp-spmenu a:hover {
 background: #258ecd;
}

.cbp-spmenu a:active {
 background: #afdefa;
 color: #47a3da;
}

/* Orientation-dependent styles for the content of the menu */

.cbp-spmenu-vertical {
 width: 240px;
 height: 100%;
 top: 0;
 z-index: 100;
}

.cbp-spmenu-vertical a {
 
 padding: 1em;
}

.cbp-spmenu-horizontal {
 width: 100%;
 height: 150px;
 left: 0;
 z-index: 100;
 overflow: hidden;
}

.cbp-spmenu-horizontal h3 {
 height: 100%;
 width: 20%;
 float: left;
}

.cbp-spmenu-horizontal a {
 float: left;
 width: 20%;
 padding: 0.8em;
 border-left: 1px solid #258ecd;
}

/* Vertical menu that slides from the left or right */



.cbp-spmenu-right {
    display: none;
 right: 0px;
}

.cbp-spmenu-right.cbp-spmenu-open {
 right: 0px;
}

/* Transitions */

.cbp-spmenu,
.cbp-spmenu-push {
 -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
 -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease;
 transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

/* Example media queries */

@media screen and (max-width: 55.1875em){

 .cbp-spmenu-horizontal {
  font-size: 75%;
  height: 110px;
 }

 .cbp-spmenu-top {
  top: -110px;
 }

 .cbp-spmenu-bottom {
  bottom: -110px;
 }

}

@media screen and (max-height: 26.375em){

 .cbp-spmenu-vertical {
  font-size: 90%;
  width: 190px;
 }

 .cbp-spmenu-left,
 .cbp-spmenu-push-toleft {
  left: -190px;
 }

 .cbp-spmenu-right {
  right: -190px;
 }

 .cbp-spmenu-push-toright {
  left: 190px;
 }
}

.nav-free-quote .button-orange {
    width: 80%;
    margin: 25px auto 0;
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: center;
}
.nav-free-quote .button-orange:hover {
    background-color: #ffb22a;
}
.nav-free-quote .button-orange i {
   color: #fff;
}
.sub-nav {
  display: none;
}
/***** PHOTO HEAD *****
****************************************************************************/
.photo-head {
    height:100%; 
    overflow-y:hidden;
    background-image: url(../images/home-bg.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment:fixed;
    background-size:cover;
}
.photo-head2 {
    height:100%; 
    overflow-y:hidden;
    background-image: url(../images/home-bg3.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment:fixed;
    background-size:cover;
    background-position: bottom;
    height: 700px;
}
.photo-head3 {
    height:100%; 
    overflow-y:hidden;
    background-image: url(../images/home-bg3.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment:fixed;
    background-size:cover;
    height: 700px;
}
.bg-overlay {
    height:100%; 
    overflow-y:hidden;
    background-color: rgba(28, 28, 28, 0.18);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment:fixed;
    background-size:cover;
}
.bg-overlay2 {
    height:100%; 
    overflow-y:hidden;
    background-color: rgba(28, 28, 28, 0.46);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment:fixed;
    background-size:cover;
}
.bg-overlay3 {
    height:100%; 
    overflow-y:hidden;
    background-color: rgba(28, 28, 28, 0.18);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment:fixed;
    background-size:cover;
}
.call-to-action {
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 150px auto 0;
    text-align: right;
}
.call-to-action3 {
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 150px auto 0;
    text-align: right;
}
.call-to-action-block {
    display: block;
    width: 52.5%;
    float: right;
    background-color: rgba(28, 28, 28, 0.6);
    padding: 15px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
.call-to-action .cta-title {
    font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 68px;
    color: #fff;
    margin: 10px 0 15px 0;
    padding: 0;
    line-height: 55px;
}
.call-to-action3 .cta-title {
    font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 68px;
    color: #fff;
    margin: 10px 0 15px 0;
    padding: 0;
    line-height: 55px;
}
.call-to-action span {
    display: block;
    font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: 30px;
    color: #fff;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 10px 0 0 0;
    line-height: 35px;
}
.call-to-action3 span {
    display: block;
    font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: 30px;
    color: #fff;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 10px 0 0 0;
    line-height: 35px;
}
/***** INDEX *****
***************************************************************/
/** why eid **/
.why-eid {
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 50px 0;
}
.why-eid h1{
    font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;
    font-size: 80px;
    font-weight: 300;
    margin: 0 0 20px 0;
    padding: 0;
    line-height: 80px;
}
/** three **/
.pre-home-three {
    padding: 50px 0;
    background-color: #fff;
}
.feature,.project {
    padding: 0 20px;
}
.feature i {
    font-size: 70px;
    color: #169CD0;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
}
.feature i:hover {
    transform: scale(1.2);
    transition: all .2s ease;
}
.feature a, .project a {
    font-size: 21px;
    color: #4c5867;
    font-weight: 400;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
.pre-home-lead-out{
    padding: 100px 0;
    background: linear-gradient(
      rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9), 
      rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.45)
    ),url(../images/home-lead-out-bg.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-size: cover;
}
.home-lead-out-left {
}
.home-lead-out-left p {
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 26px;
    color: #fff;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    margin: 0;
}
.home-lead-out-right {
    margin: 15px 0 0 0;
}
.pre-recent-projects {
    padding: 50px 0;
}
.project img {
    margin: 0 0 5px 0;
}
.project h3 {
    text-align: left;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.recent-projects h2 {
    font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;
    font-size: 38px;
    font-weight: 300;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}




/***** FOOTER *****
***************************************************************/

.pre-footer {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #1A1A1A;
    padding: 25px 0;
}
/*.sub-nav {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
}*/
.footer ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 20px;
    padding: 0;
}
.footer ul li a {
    font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 300;
    color: #888;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
.footer ul li a:hover {
    color: #169CD0;
    transition: all .75s ease;
}
.footer-logo {
    padding: 8px 0;
}
.footer-logo img {
    height: 50px;
    width: 195px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.foot-mail, .foot-phone {
    display: inline;
    margin: 0 10px
}
.foot-mail, .foot-phone {
    font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #888;
}
.foot-mail a, .foot-phone a {
    color: #888;
}
.foot-mail i, .foot-phone i {
    font-weight: 900;
    margin: 0 5px
}
.copyright p {
    font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #888;
    margin: 10px 0 0 0;
}



/****! responsive-nav.js 1.0.39 by @viljamis ****
***************************************************************/

.js .nav-collapse {
    clip: rect(0 0 0 0);
    max-height: 0;
    position: fixed;
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    zoom: 1;
    width: 100%;
}

.nav-collapse.opened {
  max-height: 9999px;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 780px) {
    .js .nav-collapse {
        position: fixed;
        z-index: 200;
    }
    .js .nav-collapse.closed {
        max-height: none;
        z-index: 200;
    }
    .nav-toggle {
        display: none !important;
    }
}
```

```html
<body class="cbp-spmenu-push-toleft">
    
    <?php include_once("analytics.php") ?>    
    <div class="pre-head">
        <div class="grid-container head">
            <div class="grid-100 mobile-grid-100" id="head_container">
                <div class="compact fatnav_header" id="header">
                    <div id="header_logo">
                        <a href="index.html" class="logo_link"><img src="assets/images/logo.svg" title="Elegance in Design, Woodland CA." alt="Elegance In Design main logo" /></a>
                    </div>
                    <div id="fat_nav">
                        <nav class="cbp-spmenu cbp-spmenu-vertical cbp-spmenu-right cbp-spmenu-open" id="cbp-spmenu-s2">
                            <button id="close"><img src="assets/images/hamburger-white-close.svg" /></button>
                            <ul id="nav">
                                <li class="parent"><a class="nav-top" href="#">Web Design <i class="fa fa-angle-double-down"></i></a>
                                    <ul class="sub-nav">
                                        <li><a class="nav-top" href="self-storage-ws.html">Self Storage Websites</a></li>
                                        <li><a class="nav-top" href="responsive-ws.html">Responsive Websites</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                                <li class="parent"><a class="nav-top" href="#">Internet Marketing <i class="fa fa-angle-double-down"></i></a>
                                    <ul class="sub-nav">
                                        <li><a class="nav-top" href="seo.html">Real SEO</a></li>
                                        <li><a class="nav-top" href="ppc.html">PPC (Pay Per Click) Ads</a></li>
                                        <li><a class="nav-top" href="social-media-marketing.html">Social Media Marketing</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                                <li class="parent"><a class="nav-top" href="hosting.html">Website Hosting</a></li>
                                <li class="parent"><a class="nav-top" href="#">About Us <i class="fa fa-angle-double-down"></i></a>
                                    <ul class="sub-nav">
                                        <li><a class="nav-top" href="about.html">About EiD</a></li>
                                        <li><a class="nav-top" href="careers.html">Careers</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                                <li class="parent"><a class="nav-top" href="contact.html">Contact Us</a></li>
                            </ul>
                            <div class="nav-free-quote">
                                <a class="button-orange" href="free-quote.html"><i class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></i>&nbsp;Free Quote</a>
                            </div>
                        </nav>    
                        <button id="showRightPush"><img src="assets/images/hamburger-white-open.svg" /></button>    
                    </div><!-- END OF FAT NAV -->
                </div><!-- END OF HEADER -->
            </div><!-- END OF HEAD CONTAINER -->
        </div><!-- END OF HEAD -->
    </div><!-- END OF PRE HEAD -->
    
    <div class="photo-head2">
        <div class="bg-overlay2">
            <div class="grid-container"> 
                <div class="grid-100 mobile-grid-100 call-to-action">
                    <!--<div class="call-to-action-block">-->
                        <span class="cta-title">Best Your Competition!<br>
                        <span>OUR SPECIALTY: helping local businesses market<br/> and advertise online EFFECTIVELY.</span></span>
                        <a class="button" href="internet-marketing.html"><i class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></i>&nbsp;Check out our services</a>
                    <!--</div>-->
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div><!-- END OF PHOTO HEAD -->
    
   
    
<!-- SCRIPTS -->
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="./assets/javascripts/scripts.js"></script>

</body>
```